# Add picture with ImageTk for Multiple Windows/Frames in Tkinter GUI with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a mutiple-frames GUI. The code I am using is working fine for this purpose. However, when I add some pictures in some frames, the GUI appears in two windows: one with normal functionalities and arrangement; one with nothing inside it. If I close either of them, both of them are closed.

I use Python 2.7.

Would anybody please explain to me what happened?

Edit: I know the reason now. It is because I use tk.Toplevel instead of tk.Tk. With tk.Tk, I have no problem with double windows but I cannot get my pictures shown. Any help?

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk   # python3
#import Tkinter as tk   # python
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
img = Image.open('arrow.png')

class SampleApp(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.arrow = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=TITLE_FONT)
#        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label.grid(row=0)

        arrow1 = tk.Label(self, image = self.controller.arrow)
        arrow2 = tk.Label(self, image = self.controller.arrow)
        arrow1.grid(row=1,column=0)
        arrow2.grid(row=2,column=0)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.grid(row=1,column=1)
        button2.grid(row=2,column=1)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label.grid(row=0)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.grid(row=1,column=1)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the `image=...` option into your label in PageOne and PageTwo. I have added it. ;)

Also, removed the Toplevel. Alternatively, you can still use Toplevel as you did and hide the `root=tk.Tk()` window after it has been created.

```
#import tkinter as tk   # python3
import Tkinter as tk   # python
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
img = Image.open('arrow.png')

class SampleApp(tk.Frame): #change to tk.Frame
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs): #added parent
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs) #added parent

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(parent) #changed self to parent
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.arrow = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=TITLE_FONT)
#        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label.grid(row=0)

        arrow1 = tk.Label(self, image = self.controller.arrow)
        arrow2 = tk.Label(self, image = self.controller.arrow)
        arrow1.grid(row=1,column=0)
        arrow2.grid(row=2,column=0)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.grid(row=1,column=1)
        button2.grid(row=2,column=1)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=TITLE_FONT,
                         image = self.controller.arrow) # Added
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label.grid(row=0)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.grid(row=1,column=1)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=TITLE_FONT,
                         image = self.controller.arrow) # Added
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() #Added
    app = SampleApp(root) #added root
    root.mainloop()
```